# how to implement odd numbers in a new array?

Tags: arrays, perl

I want to output only the odd numbers from an array with the numbers from 1-100 in a new array. I have no idea how to do this.

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

my @zahlen = (1..100);

foreach my $zahlen (@zahlen){
    if ($zahlen % 2) {
        print "$zahlen ist ungerade\n";
    } else {
        print "$zahlen ist gerade\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71088824/4653379

Comment: You've asked a lot of basic questions in the past 2 days. If you want to learn Perl, then you really should read a tutorial or a book. And, you should consider spending some time working out those exercises by yourself: if we tell you the answer, you learn nothing...

Comment: I am intrigued as to where you are learning Perl in German. I did an apprenticeship many years ago at one of a handful of companies in Germany that used Perl (and I train Perl devs now). I'd love to have a chat, feel free to reach out to me. :)

Comment: [`perldoc -f push`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push).

Comment: Maybe of interest? In Raku you would write: `my @zahlen = (1..100); put @zahlen.grep( * % 2);`  to return only odd numbers. https://raku.org

Comment: @Dada 

I started a dual degree in a company and am working on a self-made draft of tasks, some of which are not quite finished yet. In order to solve the corresponding tasks, some information is missing, which means that I cannot progress without help.
If you can recommend me a site or something similar where I can acquire basic knowledge about Perl, I would be happy

Comment: Unfortunately, I learnt Perl a while ago, with a questionable tutorial, so I don't really know what good beginner tutorials there are nowadays... @simbabque any suggestion? (pinging you because you've commented on the post (and thus you are pingable) and I expect that you'll have some ideas ;) )

Comment: I would start with the Learning Perl book. That's the best beginner resource. OP's company should be willing to pay for that if money is an issue. Gabor's https://perlmaven.com/ is a very good free resource, although it's not really a class. SO is of course good, and I would also look at [codereview.se]. Post some finished code there and we'll give you constructive feedback. There are also Facebook groups for help, and of course perlmonks. https://www.perl-community.de/ is a German language message board that is quite helpful, too.

Comment: Apart from that, you're welcome to reach out to me in German or English if you want to have a chat @grotivanhelden. You can find a way to contact me through my profile here or on CPAN. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create new array and add the odd numbers

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my @zahlen = (1..100);
my @ungerade;
my $i = 0;

foreach my $zahlen (@zahlen){
    if ($zahlen % 2){
        $ungerade[$i] = $zahlen;
        $i = $i + 1;
    }

}

print "@ungerade"
```

Comment: 1) `$i += 1`, `$i++`. Take advantage of the advanced operators. 2) `push @ungerade, $zahlen`. No sense in keeping track of indexes. 3) `for my $z (1 .. 100)`. No sense in storing numbers in an array that you are never going to use.

Comment: ok thanks. But what does the index value do in the context ? [$i]

Can you fill the array with operations?

Comment: @TLP The goal was to make it as simple as possible. grotivanhelden the index is used to create a new item in the array

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with [`grep`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep) instead of a for-loop:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings; 

my @zahlen = (1..100);
my @odds = grep { $_ % 2 == 1 } @zahlen;
```